# Iterating from a dictionary with proper print formatting

Tags: python, list, dictionary, file-handling

I have this dictionary and I need it to be formatted in a table like manner to a text file.

```
dictionary_lines = {'1-2': (69.18217255912117, 182.95794152905918), '2-3': (35.825144800822954, 175.40503498180715), '3-4': (37.34332738254673, 97.30771061242511), '4-5': (57.026590289091914, 97.33437880141743), '5-6': (57.23912298419586, 14.32271997820363), '6-7': (55.61382561917492, 351.4794228420951), '7-8': (41.21551406933976, 275.1365340619268), '8-1': (57.83213034291623, 272.6560961904868)}
```

As of right now I'm working on printing them out first before working on writing a new file. I'm stuck on how to properly format them. Here's what I got so far:

```
for item in dictionary_lines:
    print ("{l}\t{d:<10.3f}\t{a:<10.3f}".format(l= ,d =,a = ))
```

I want it to be printed like this:

```
Lines[tab] Distances [tab]  Azimuth from the South
Key 0       value1 in tuple0  Value2 in tuple0
```

Comment: Have you heard about pandas? I think this could help here. You can create a pandas DataFrame from a dictionary. It has a .from_dict() method. and then you could just print your dataframe and have a nice output.

Comment: Okay, so... what exactly is preventing you from finishing "what you got so far"? What part of it don't you know how to do, or what is confusing you about it? Please read [ask], and *ask an actual question*.

Comment: @chrisaramar i haven't heard of that. i will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the data from the dictionary in the `format()`.

Also, consider using `items()` to iterate over key-value pairs of a dictionary as:

```
for key, value in dictionary_lines.items():
    print ("l={}\td={:<10.3f}\ta={:<10.3f}".format(key, value[0], value[1]))

l=1-2   d=69.182        a=182.958   
l=2-3   d=35.825        a=175.405   
l=3-4   d=37.343        a=97.308    
l=4-5   d=57.027        a=97.334    
l=5-6   d=57.239        a=14.323    
l=6-7   d=55.614        a=351.479   
l=7-8   d=41.216        a=275.137   
l=8-1   d=57.832        a=272.656
```

Comment: Yeah I figured, using the dictionary in the `format()` command got me an error. thank you for this!